# store multiple value on enter with 1 textbox?

Tags: c#, litedb

In C# with LiteDB i working on a little project, I'm searching for a way to add entry to a datagridview with 5 columns + 1 Textbox.

On datagridView, i have a colID so if i enter on textbox *dev5* dgv select this row and i can write on their row like this example:

on textbox i type :

**dev5** [Enter] -> line selected by dgv -> **2** [Enter] -> **5** [Enter]..

```
 |colID |col2|col3|col4|col5|
 |--------------------------|
 |dev3  |    |    |    |    |
 |dev4  |    |    |    |    |
 |--------------------------|
*|dev5  | 2  |  5 |    |    |
 |--------------------------|
 |dev6  |    |    |    |    |
------------------------------
```

I need to store value of textbox on [Enter] to a array like {dev5,2,5,"",""}

and Insert to database in one shot because Actually, on every [enter] its update my table like this :

```
dev5;2
dev5;2;5
dev5;2;5;8
dev5;2;5;8;9
```

Like you see, it's not optimized so for a better result but i need just the last line..

Any idea for solving this problem are welcome

Comment: In theory, could you simply capture the contents of the textbox when enter is pressed and store those values in a list? The list should be pretty easy to iterate over.

Comment: @JDDavis yes interesting approach!but how i can store it to my list with 1 textbox if i click [Enter] 3 times with different value each time?

Comment: You only need to ensure you clear the textbox each time enter is pressed, it should be relatively straightforward to update the list each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential method would look something like this

```
public List<string> Values = new List<string>();
public void UpdateValues()
{
    var value = textBox1.Text;

    Values.Add(value);
    textBox1.Clear();

}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.Return)
    {
        UpdateValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i found my problem!! I'm declaring my List<> inside my textbox so it's not working before because we need to declare outside of my method. thanks for your example it's perfect!!!